# Python CookieJar saves file with no cookies

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies

I'm in Python 3.8 and have a `http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar`, which I have manually populated with cookies as follows:

```py
jar = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar('saved-cookies.txt')
cookie = http.cookiejar.Cookie(1, 'name', 'value', 80, 80, 'domain.com', 'domain.com', '.domain.com', '/path', '/path', True, False, False, 'comment', 'comment_url', 'rest')
jar.set_cookie(cookie)
```

And when I call `jar.save()`, the file it writes contains only the following:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
```

There are no cookies. When I look at `jar._cookies`, I can see the cookies that I've created. When I look at `len(jar._cookies)`, it returns the number of cookies that I've created. Why does the file contain no cookies?

What must I do to get my cookie written to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `save` function ignores session cookies, and with the `expires` argument set to `False`, this cookie is a session cookie. Overcome this by calling save with `ignore_expired=True`:

```py
jar.save(ignore_expired=True)
```